# Dual-booting from Thunderbolt device

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, thunderbolt

recently, I bought a new laptop and get some money from the old one. For work/school I am using a Linux system, but I am contemplating, to buy an eGPU enclosure.

I noticed, that HP Omen Accelerator Shell also supports disk expansion, which get me thinking: Would it be possible to boot from HP Accelerator if I would put an SSD disk (to install Windows onto) and GTX 1050Ti into it?

So in end, I would end up with:
1x Laptop with only Linux + enclosure, from which I can boot a Windows if I wanted to relax for a bit.

P.S.: The new laptop has 2x Thunderbolts (4x PCIe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: **yes**, you should be able to.

The long answer is: **it depends**.
When you have your Windows installed on that SSD and it is connected to your laptop, make sure that:

1. Your **BIOS**/**UEFI** recognize it.
2. Your Linux system recognizes it (using `lsblk` or any partition tool for example).
3. You can boot into your Windows by setting the boot option to your SSD.

If each of those is true, then you should be safe to run `os-prober` (which tries to detect any other OS on your system) and `update-grub` (to update your GRUB configuration with the newly detected OS [Windows]) on your Linux system. Then when booting into Linux (GRUB), you should have an option to boot either into Linux or into Windows.

However, keep in mind that you might have some issues:

1. `os-prober` might fail to recognize the Windows on your SSD. In such case, you'll have to [manually configure GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Multi_002dboot-manual-config.html).
2. Everything on Linux is a file, even devices. When you connect a device like a hard/soft drive to your PC, you can access it via a path like `/dev/sda`, where `sda` is that drive. Generally speaking, the first drive connected is `sda`, the second `sdb`, and so on. The issue with this is that GRUB uses those paths to load up your OS. If your GRUB is configured to load your Windows from `/dev/sdb` (for example), because when you've configured GRUB the SSD has been your 2nd drive connected to your PC, then in a scenario where that label is changed or there was another drive connected before the SSD (even an USB), the SSD would get a label like `sdc`, and GRUB will fail to load Windows.

**Important note:**
You might not be able to install a regular version of **Windows** on an external drive. Thus, if the HP Omen Accelerator Shell adds the disk as external, then you'll have problems installing Windows, as newer versions of Windows (8+) will not allow you to install Windows on an external drive. You'll need a portable version of Windows for that - [Windows To Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go). If you run into this issue, here are other (possible) ways to install your Windows on externals:

[AOMEI - How to install Windows 10 on an external hard drive](https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/install-windows-10-on-external-hard-drive-3889.html)
[EaseUS - How to install Windows 10 on an external hard drive](https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/install-windows-10-on-external-hard-drive-3889.html)

Comment: Och, I was counting on this, but wouldn't mere selecting boot device in bios work and would be easier?
Like I fear that once I disconnect the e-GPU, the GRUB would panic, about missing drive.

Comment: @Kyras Choosing a different boot option each time on boot might be a hassle on some systems. And no, GRUB shouldn't panic, however, if the SSD isn't connected, then when you select to boot into Windows 10 from GRUB, it will throw you an error.

Comment: @Fanatique It might not be possible to install Windows if the SSD in the HP Omen Accelerator Shell is seen as "external".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Reference to that statement? What makes you think that? It doesn't matter if it's external or not from my experience. You can install an OS in an external USB and still make GRUB boot from it.

Comment: Yes, you can make Grub boot pretty much everything from everywhere. OTOH, the Windows installer dettects and refuses to install in an external drive for reasons that only Microsoft knows - but we can guess it's about selling the Windows to Go feature available only in pro/enterprise editions. And again, I'm not saying in this case it'll be seen as external and neither implying your answer is incorrect. And there are third-party software being market as being able to allow that but this being third-party implies workaround instead of the straightforward installation as designed.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I understand now, thanks for clarifying. I will add an emphasized note about that in my answer, else will be all up to OP. Thanks for the heads up though! And yeah, I can totally see Microsoft doing that, it's something they'd do.